# Audience Manager integration with LDAP / AD

Tags: audience-manager

Do we have a feature or connector available which can import LDAP/AD users into Audience Manager and also sync up with LDAP/AD for all user updates?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such functionality. However you can use Event System to trigger an event when a User is `created / updated / deleted` so that you can create a Contact for that User in Audience Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Also in 2013 SP1 you can use a Webservice/API to Import/Export data in/out Audience Manager
it also has functionality to only update changed contacts

Comment: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/introducing-the-new-audience-manager-web-service